# Rectangle between midpoints of rotated rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

I need to draw a rectangle between the midpoints of two rotated rectangles (shown below).

How do I do this?

My current code is shown below.

**Current code**

```
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[thick,fill=yellow!40, rotate around={26.5:(3.1,-5)}] (3,0) rectangle (3.2,-5);
\draw[thick,fill=yellow!40, rotate around={-26.5:(3.1,-5)}] (3,0) rectangle (3.2,-5);
\draw[fill=black] (3.1,-5) circle(0.11);
\node at (3.1,-5.3) {A};
```

**Current result**

[image]

**Mockup of wanted result**

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you intend to have?. I don't quite follow your requirement as such.

Comment: @HarishKumar I've updated the question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'll make sure to do that from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define two `coordinates` a and b, then draw a line with desired thickness. Change the `pos` value as you wish.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[thick,fill=yellow!40, rotate around={26.5:(3.1,-5)}] (3,0) rectangle (3.2,-5)coordinate[pos=0.5](a);
\draw[thick,fill=yellow!40, rotate around={-26.5:(3.1,-5)}] (3,0) rectangle (3.2,-5)coordinate[pos=0.5](b);
\draw[fill=black] (3.1,-5) circle(0.11);
\node at (3.1,-5.3) {A};
\draw[line width=2pt] (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `rectangles` you can draw rectangular `nodes` and make reference to thier `center` anchors.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thin,gray] (0,0) node[above] {(0,0)} grid (6,-6) node[below] {(6,-6)};
\node[draw, thick, fill=yellow!40, minimum height=5cm, minimum width=2mm, 
       inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=south, rotate=26.5] at (3.1,-5) (a){};
\node[draw, thick, fill=yellow!40, minimum height=5cm, minimum width=2mm,
       inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=south, rotate=-26.5] at (3.1,-5) (b){};
\draw[fill=black] (a.south) circle(0.11) node[below, outer sep=1mm]{A};
\draw[ultra thick] (a.center)--(b.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this neatly in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) using the `center` operator, which returns a `pair` representing the center of the `bbox` of a given path.

[image: An upside down A-shape]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

pair apex; 
numeric u, alpha; 
path rectangle[]; 

u = 1cm;
apex = (3u, -5u); 
alpha = 53; % angle between the two legs

rectangle0 = unitsquare shifted 1/2 left xscaled 0.2u yscaled 5u;
rectangle1 = rectangle0 rotated +1/2 alpha shifted apex;
rectangle2 = rectangle0 rotated -1/2 alpha shifted apex;

rectangle3 = unitsquare shifted 1/2 down yscaled 0.2u 
                        xscaled length(center rectangle2 - center rectangle1)
                        shifted center rectangle1;

forsuffixes $=1,2,3:
  fill rectangle$ withcolor 0.4[white,red+green];
  draw rectangle$; 
endfor

fill fullcircle scaled .22u shifted apex;
label("A" infont "phvr8r",apex+8 down);

endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the same rotation to the centers of the non-rotated rectangle.  In other words, the center of the non-rotated rectangles would be `(3.1,-2.5)`.  Hence the centers of the rotated rectangles are:

```
        ([rotate around={26.5:(3.1,-5)}]3.1,-2.5)
```

and

```
        ([rotate around={-26.5:(3.1,-5)}]3.1,-2.5)
```

Connecting these points yields:

[image]

I have just drawn a line, but that should let you draw any desired rectangle based on those coordinates.

### Notes:

- One of drawbacks of this solution is that you need to specify the rotation values twice.  Hence, using `\coordinates` (as per Harish Kumar's solution) or `\nodes` (as per Ignasi's solution) isbetter.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (6,0);
    \draw[thick,fill=yellow!40, rotate around={26.5:(3.1,-5)} ]  (3,0) rectangle (3.2,-5) node (a) {};
    \draw[thick,fill=yellow!40, rotate around={-26.5:(3.1,-5)}]  (3,0) rectangle (3.2,-5) node (b) {};
    \draw[fill=black] (3.1,-5) circle(0.11);
    \node at (3.1,-5.3) {A};
    \draw [red, ultra thick] 
        ([rotate around={26.5:(3.1,-5)}]3.1,-2.5) -- 
        ([rotate around={-26.5:(3.1,-5)}]3.1,-2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\psset{fillstyle = solid}
\begin{pspicture}(6.2,6.52)
  \rput{115}(3.23,0.18){\psframe[fillcolor = yellow!60](0,0)(7,0.3)}
  \rput{65}(3.23,0.05){\psframe[fillcolor = yellow!60](0,0)(7,0.3)}
  \pscircle[fillcolor = black](3.1,0.12){0.15}
  \psframe[fillcolor = black](1.59,3.3)(4.6,3.4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]